# CHAR(10) Added to Imported CSV and Can't Remove with REPLACE

Tags: sql, sql-server, replace

I am importing a CSV into SQL, here is the first couple of lines:

```
Cust Code,Cust Name,Contact Name,Address,City,State,Zip,Country Cd,Phone,Fax #,

000064,OFIX                       ,Rich Clay ,,,,,USA,1234567890,1234567890,

000199,STMETER                   ,ACCOUNTS PAYABLE,,,,,USA,1234567890,1234567890,

000292,BESSY INTERNATIONAL INC            ,TIM BARSEY,BARSEY@BESSY.COM, ,, ,USA,1234567890,1234567890,
```

There is a line between every record, and I think it's adding a character at the beginning of the Cust Code.

When I output the data, it looks like this, which looks like it's adding `CHAR(10)`

```
id  ascii   char
1   10   
2   48       0
3   50       2
4   52       4
5   55       7 
6   49       1
7   54       6
```

I've tried the following, and it doesn't remove the `CHAR(10)`

```
UPDATE [proc_customer] SET [CustID] = REPLACE([CustID], CHAR(10), '')   WHERE [CustID] LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
UPDATE [proc_customer] SET [CustID] = REPLACE([CustID], CHAR(10), '')   WHERE [CustID] LIKE CHAR(10) + '%'
```

I've doublechecked that `[CustID]` is `VARCHAR(MAX)` so the REPLACE should work.

What am I missing?

Comment: Maybe a different character? char(13) perhaps? There could be a few others that will do that and are non printable. You will have to evaluate what is in your data.

Comment: Run `SELECT CONVERT(VARBINARY(MAX), 'CustId')` to see exactly what chars are in there, or just remove the blank lines from the CSV.

Comment: You'd need to look at the file in a hex editor to see what's really going on (e.g.: VS Code with the HexDump extension). I suspect that whatever's generating the file is using `\r\n` for line breaks instead of `\015\012` and its stdlib is "helping" by converting `\r\n` to `\015\015\012` for you (i.e.: two carriage return characters).

Comment: @Bohemian Output of that is is `0x0A303234373136`  Some of the files are over 400k lines and I'll prob need to rerun these a dozen times, so removing the blank lines isn't very practical.

Comment: The list I put up there is a function I wrote that goes through a string and runs: `SELECT ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inStr, @cnt, 1))` and `CHAR(ASCII(SUBSTRING(@inStr, @cnt, 1)))` on every character in the string.  It says the first one is CHAR(10), but I can't get rid of it! :(

Comment: According to Notepad++ the end of each record has CRLF, and the blank line is just LF

Comment: CRLF is char(10) and char(13). Try replacing both of them.

Comment: @SeanLange I did, I have a couple REPLACE for CHAR(10) and for CHAR(13).  The end result is that one character I can't seem to get rid of.

Answer (score 0):

Once I identified that it was CHAR(10), I changed the SQL Server Import Row Delimiter from `{CR}{LF}` to `{CR}{LF}{LF}` and it imported correctly.

Still doesn't answer why it couldn't be removed, but this at least allowed me to move forward.